# VirtualBox Fedora 16 "Switch to fullscreen" weird behavior

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I have 2 widescreen monitors, one is 19inch and the other is 23 inch.
I have installed Fedora 16 on VirtualBox [Windows 7 Host]. I installed the virtualbox guest additions and got the gnome-shell running, but I am running into some weird behavior. When I place the virtualBox linux guest machine window on the 23 inch and click "Switch to fullscreen", the window swaps monitors and moves to the 19inch monitor and goes fullscreen on that one instead of the 23inch.

How do I get it to go fullscreen on the 23inch ?

Help !
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fullscreen-mode (Host+F) you can press Host+Home to bring up a context menu:

View -> Virtual Screen 1 -> Use Host Screen 2

Comment: Thanks, I just looked up at virtualbox bugs : https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6722